# Unlist a list within a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm quite new to R (and to this website) and I'm stuck with a simple problem, yet I have not found a solution for it. 
I work on a dataset containing potential density values measured by a CTD within a water column at several dates. I want to group those measures by date within a data frame.

What I have at the beginning :

```
ctd<-read.csv("data/ptb_ctd.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
julian <- as.numeric(as.Date(ctd$date, format= "%d/%m/%Y")) + 17280
ctd$julian <- julian
```

Example from the initial "ctd" data frame (after adding julian days as shown above) :

```
            id             station   date       ...  pot_density julian
            B12171_01.cnv  B+        19/06/2012 ...  28.73863    32790
```

Now I want to take "pot_density" values (several for each date, ie same "date" & "julian" in the data frame) and store them in a new data frame, so julian days become rows, and columns are formed by every single "pot_density" measurement for that day/row.

```
dens<-data.frame()
dens<-aggregate(pot_density ~ julian, data=ctd, FUN=paste)
```

Now I have in the "dens" data frame:

```
julian   pot_density
27548    c("28.4698015312665", "28.4704581365093", "28.4706453687...)
...      ...
```

I want now to unlist the "pot_density" values into n columns for each rows, and that's where I'm stuck. I need that to be able to apply a function detecting the pycnocline for every sampling date, and to plot the interannual variation of the pycnocline...

I tried several function :

```
dens <- str_split_fixed(dens, pattern=",", n=Inf)

dens<-split(dens$pot_density, julian)

dens<-spread(dens, key="julian", value="pot_density", convert=FALSE, fill=NA)

dens<-lapply(dens$pot_dens, FUN=spread)

dens<-reshape(dens,varying=NULL, v.names = pot_density,timevar=julian)
```

Mind that needed packages were loaded beforehand; I searched for a similar problem on the forum but could not find any related topics (or could not understand it was similar to my own problem, again I'm new to R and not very skillful in general when it comes to coding).

Did I miss any function that would do exactly what I want to do here ? Do I not correctly enter arguments for the above functions ?

```
    > dput(dens[1:10,])
structure(list(julian = c(27548, 27555, 27562, 27569, 27576, 
27583, 27588, 27590, 27597, 27604), pot_density = structure(list(
    `001` = c(28.4698015312665, 28.4704581365093, 28.4706453687199, 
    28.4713658034907, 28.4715960505218, 28.4713220614417, 28.4719434816675, 
    28.4716438928615, 28.4719381177117, 28.4724430855808, 28.4729393244543, 
    28.4730915014395, 28.472882160301, 28.4730989562061, 28.4737587846116, 
    28.4739971132756, 28.4742267211307, 28.4738625366081, 28.4743244355707, 
    28.4742699732992, 28.4750118357917, 28.4756588360735, 28.4750839098374, 
    28.475580174204, 28.4752806092672, 28.4752907658838, 28.4753439905428, 
    28.4754444132004, 28.4763878641565, 28.4769744045504, 28.4774661037934, 
    28.4779106145504, 28.4778992589288, 28.4780299398942, 28.4781821563902, 
    28.4780933780096, 28.4778841043003, 28.4779158290446, 28.4781583123097, 
    28.478112611112, 28.4778043852182, 28.4779263792905, 28.4778719824292, 
    28.4782739109617, 28.4782282194151, 28.4779241414187, 28.4777620899599, 
    28.4779143365161, 28.4776102589242, 28.4776204821671, 28.4776737743953, 
    28.4772624867899, 28.477105022565, 28.476865564174, 28.4773490796508, 
    28.4768645036095, 28.4771716304488, 28.4775433527325, 28.4772223424882, 
    28.476673185145, 28.4766705975139, 28.4765172931616, 28.4767341623638, 
    28.4764260035167, 28.4763373003382, 28.4766788132085, 28.476667545619, 
    28.4764670489733, 28.4764644743016, 28.4765778578981, 28.4766784022163, 
    28.4767015185159, 28.4766173680835, 28.4766918586333, 28.4767621912918, 
    28.4768370707511, 28.4769806916393, 28.4767458510698, 28.4764551085279, 
    28.4765602010568, 28.476802425097, 28.4769630495639), `002` = c(28.3854267585043, 
    28.3880639603979, 28.3910917267553, 28.4010348607969, 28.412893371411, 
    28.4224347755983, 28.4397727476692, 28.4452234057089, 28.4458186136571, 
    28.4457641137874, 28.446195710763, 28.4465498862407, 28.447359840826, 
    28.4499888764699, 28.4505841110556, 28.4524108843229, 28.4528041503486, 
    28.4527927667575, 28.452415805632, 28.4524259732418, 28.4525741718935, 
    28.4532899260366, 28.4532011281387, 28.4537061521382, 28.4546198491653, 
    28.4549269344061, 28.4554837839473, 28.4560318858134, 28.4558656729801, 
    28.4565168108963, 28.4580714631404, 28.459325139906, 28.4597742710259, 
    28.4601931366756, 28.4605089496824, 28.4610011510342, 28.461360027075, 
    28.4612712582959, 28.4615783463796, 28.4619069702394, 28.4623304367783, 
    28.4650345230459, 28.4681773148704, 28.4690697062383, 28.4696951373126, 
    28.4699591415863, 28.4705974387778, 28.4711798263061, 28.4713535340786, 
    28.4729642397172, 28.4746824791714, 28.4755574246585, 28.4772239205411, 
    28.4791527947114, 28.479842680591, 28.4809713436873, 28.4810804730612, 
    28.4811121691725, 28.4812901464768, 28.4810680352355, 28.4815299275549, 
    28.4815057026794, 28.4812620912953, 28.4812292832326, 28.4814502899062, 
    28.4814045681574, 28.4812943327379, 28.481261535575, 28.4814266226144, 
    28.4814583458203, 28.4814126352126, 28.4815433020397, 28.4813556469537, 
    28.4814863176814, 28.4813761037037, 28.4815197036496, 28.4816848098903, 
    28.48116592119, 28.4809912072346, 28.4808035711785, 28.4807923130716, 
    28.4808025610578, 28.4807568786814), `003` = c(28.4222716517768, 
    28.4238227923045, 28.4244286059802, 28.4247857381142, 28.4254711015647, 
    28.4251247518509, 28.4250664765352, 28.4242110005252, 28.4239874893299, 
    28.4244331766597, 28.4244307460999, 28.4252724126586, 28.4246797174392, 
    28.4243535117068, 28.4248676773248, 28.4255202537067, 28.4249313231394, 
    28.4246952098579, 28.4246927964123, 28.4246040446426, 28.4247728637667, 
    28.4249126280299, 28.424798557425, 28.4250804805711, 28.4237196924828, 
    28.4235140937569, 28.423868268211, 28.4242187238988, 28.4240563062563, 
    28.4237822331315, 28.4235297494561, 28.4236732796012, 28.4234639766482, 
    28.4233410268371, 28.4232865598096, 28.4232194426204, 28.4234061603524, 
    28.4234038076627, 28.4240423645779, 28.4242938447276, 28.4244679089948, 
    28.4243576326924, 28.4246738680081, 28.4244430125298, 28.4240699899697, 
    28.4240587249963, 28.4243787102132, 28.4246860351459, 28.4249337795727, 
    28.4255775029735, 28.4262123010587, 28.4271491888576, 28.4272242462023, 
    28.4275188694648, 28.4276497675173, 28.4287147586972, 28.430171883095, 
    28.4317926616795, 28.4344297892021, 28.4347331829235, 28.435169843448, 
    28.4359720371187, 28.4361803258259, 28.436676736914, 28.4369879156638, 
    28.4368776977024, 28.4379719221961, 28.4382360824147, 28.4386982121987, 
    28.4386311295355, 28.4391275598127, 28.4423121792161, 28.4449764223293, 
    28.4452748965623, 28.4455518106192, 28.4455621665654, 28.4474708628147, 
    28.4487640574255, 28.4482148281136, 28.4481477640663, 28.4507580309098, 
    28.453191788152, 28.4559910165078), `004` = c(28.3674842654145, 
    28.3674585519213, 28.3687819915356, 28.3701195579054, 28.3717521524566, 
    28.372642125416, 28.3742275133602, 28.3746753772148, 28.3751518674221, 
    28.3749668049827, 28.3747626363604, 28.3745749409343, 28.3772798275775, 
    28.3780912856612, 28.3790912835113, 28.3868064589531, 28.3958804355645, 
    28.3994818365295, 28.3992476445208, 28.400672676044, 28.4037720361812, 
    28.40710651225, 28.4083455760644, 28.4086190175331, 28.4097124086866, 
    28.4095712793646, 28.4098230665193, 28.4109380474015, 28.411694221968, 
    28.4131744935837, 28.4163624784683, 28.4215274536921, 28.4223266670829, 
    28.422401914773, 28.4239591967716, 28.4252535051301, 28.4253685001913, 
    28.4254653481037, 28.4260447806714, 28.4265035561596, 28.427720349943, 
    28.4290884003017, 28.4300280158559, 28.4313562610103, 28.4319120864368, 
    28.4331142634078, 28.4348025261395, 28.4359579129168, 28.4367262283533, 
    28.4392120327445, 28.4407292465714, 28.4422338288396, 28.4426492362709, 
    28.4435165077577, 28.4444791255601, 28.4450061474402, 28.4455673940549, 
    28.4454229351384, 28.4471559829733, 28.449146520896, 28.4513692873495, 
    28.4523786554164, 28.4523890271721, 28.4524768192166, 28.452883216132, 
    28.4532680268433, 28.4539714377001, 28.4546152681519, 28.4559736714407, 
    28.4579082276664, 28.4587880246834, 28.4607314323666, 28.4637244206224, 
    28.4658657310663, 28.4668140374613, 28.4680276744066, 28.4688960579203, 
    28.4696286168744, 28.4714159066223, 28.4730508468001, 28.4734165292716, 
    28.4746173674025, 28.4768223015874, 28.4790806324759), `005` = c(28.4526758311781, 
    28.4535846776619, 28.4525481478231, 28.451856584908, 28.452796815023, 
    28.4531774243305, 28.4528906364108, 28.4555429468128, 28.4588625838871, 
    28.4628239080419, 28.4746066981118, 28.4783993954704, 28.4830649177188, 
    28.4847313847029, 28.4876454410833, 28.4876856311901, 28.4883710903493, 
    28.4886005631158, 28.48842567521, 28.4883841535125, 28.4886050424675, 
    28.4883613194199, 28.4887671844829, 28.4887987867212, 28.4886582671045, 
    28.4882251409733, 28.4884546185867, 28.4885505620628, 28.489940591599, 
    28.4898002226066, 28.4908374297358, 28.4909204841301, 28.4913307399261, 
    28.4915207647966, 28.4921408576779, 28.4923781710111, 28.4923882445491, 
    28.4920930862268, 28.4923439633267, 28.4923280301164, 28.4924110117045, 
    28.4925974550899, 28.4932947417217, 28.4938071280703, 28.4939161205064, 
    28.4936256066853, 28.4937859910672, 28.4932416796044, 28.4935055716303, 
    28.4946804064894, 28.4955798990654, 28.495731830197, 28.496348426394, 
    28.497184308583, 28.4985446097212, 28.4986321483468, 28.4986767625505, 
    28.5003393077807, 28.5002159856526, 28.5000497376759, 28.4996549175607, 
    28.5004011987899, 28.5020784731132, 28.5029113589508, 28.5031890632051, 
    28.503518813731, 28.5050218566516, 28.5053072866085, 28.5052829446752, 
    28.5072791558746, 28.507418126105, 28.5117619091457, 28.513289288532, 
    28.5140645484551, 28.5142641072432, 28.5149236725456, 28.5144047544632, 
    28.5143243805205, 28.5141581735936, 28.5140311818116, 28.5144929463786, 
    28.5146663817948, 28.5146121632208, 28.5146223221971), `006` = c(28.3810645677661, 
    28.3813004672918, 28.3817133134175, 28.3831197047741, 28.3854421338472, 
    28.3871465607181, 28.3890759077963, 28.3902102320865, 28.3918042896855, 
    28.3953858494501, 28.3980196932803, 28.4004112692514, 28.4045071681478, 
    28.4072099242962, 28.4087066328063, 28.4126367239094, 28.4136233956574, 
    28.4167355043942, 28.4209358369089, 28.4270260115261, 28.4312535365273, 
    28.4374438272673, 28.4432689680516, 28.4486149408372, 28.4512622328464, 
    28.4524165801954, 28.451291051108, 28.4512323293889, 28.4523651405086, 
    28.453386129449, 28.4548632140204, 28.4555100338371, 28.4561826678098, 
    28.4571305840868, 28.4588485442057, 28.461116982636, 28.4629807022809, 
    28.4637778898482, 28.4638998839528, 28.4654069253183, 28.4661010178108, 
    28.4687266064548, 28.4703284448451, 28.4710266704567, 28.4748731605503, 
    28.4771755897834, 28.4800799759928, 28.481668318886, 28.4830932651969, 
    28.4844062566217, 28.4865964387086, 28.4884598794474, 28.4909083129323, 
    28.4931281742258, 28.4947161865994, 28.4952936224602, 28.4964728837094, 
    28.4974244422872, 28.4980148947077, 28.498888977389, 28.4992899860013, 
    28.5005381834585, 28.5025299171707, 28.5050208121045, 28.5080144643618, 
    28.5116394505137, 28.5120879762683, 28.5132847433542, 28.5140001857922, 
    28.5141222899542, 28.5147471523046, 28.5170136918687, 28.5182878702478, 
    28.5182979535264, 28.5194552147107, 28.5208744963843, 28.5208499857886, 
    28.5224323655125, 28.5237971288702, 28.5253429098379, 28.5263695153631, 
    28.5271258562564, 28.527248006475, 28.5282139926612), `007` = c(28.4428150935287, 
    28.4424508630218, 28.4417443567577, 28.4416646398661, 28.4417397473699, 
    28.4421390371037, 28.442120592066, 28.4423469529172, 28.4423356122218, 
    28.4426196264003, 28.4425488912568, 28.4422963064997, 28.4423101669536, 
    28.4423672400721, 28.4427664113, 28.4430845199499, 28.4432100343813, 
    28.4432239239436, 28.4435240263028, 28.4436080984706, 28.4432655222554, 
    28.44328479265, 28.4432176650369, 28.4433611850002, 28.4431608315413, 
    28.4429046633504, 28.4433578509172, 28.4433339312575, 28.4433658299195, 
    28.443586780443, 28.4441894718964, 28.4444519073077, 28.4446476391897, 
    28.4449171469023, 28.4452982751327, 28.4450025792219, 28.4452145723092, 
    28.4449115896032, 28.4450209283627, 28.4446694275982, 28.4443395262938, 
    28.4441176151897, 28.4439731216071, 28.44385022707, 28.4441792008458, 
    28.445123837753, 28.4453880241501, 28.4453299167678, 28.4458353149539, 
    28.4462543386658, 28.4457480468022, 28.4461112536262, 28.4463196297161, 
    28.4467044330388, 28.44669320099, 28.4467593880092, 28.4467913463193, 
    28.4468017142769, 28.4468247244756, 28.4475586978776, 28.4465573988107, 
    28.4470196343157, 28.4467977636148, 28.4467865543127, 28.4463450818671, 
    28.4463807551729, 28.4466755253629, 28.44699558456, 28.4476558489935, 
    28.447545647844, 28.4483749134677, 28.4487128468895, 28.4494698189587, 
    28.4525367472493, 28.4523834039983, 28.4533988713831, 28.4597114389207, 
    28.4601480695703, 28.4631900743702, 28.4706825902074, 28.4713645255192, 
    28.4722141080554, 28.4730032365892), `008` = c(28.4440779782437, 
    28.4505956863115, 28.4535932840915, 28.4535879092648, 28.4565387084024, 
    28.4572727573952, 28.4564823312937, 28.4569833241453, 28.4575960612924, 
    28.4575846529954, 28.4580553202582, 28.4579361864828, 28.4577914802344, 
    28.4580601711389, 28.4585436274683, 28.4587173788659, 28.4592142669674, 
    28.4593105825231, 28.4589760656734, 28.4588959957052, 28.459366652193, 
    28.459450169993, 28.4600372442301, 28.4605037909707, 28.4604667797696, 
    28.4599431386898, 28.4599317672, 28.4601142320655, 28.4596511161578, 
    28.459828961528, 28.4601144934852, 28.4604646354726, 28.4602984226369, 
    28.4602957824936, 28.4594927222365, 28.4592531932092, 28.4590869921369, 
    28.458955149021, 28.4590771281833, 28.4596811096851, 28.4597128453913, 
    28.4596671549211, 28.4597030042121, 28.4598593541125, 28.4600203119703, 
    28.4597982398213, 28.4594254267156, 28.4595474309644, 28.4595489395492, 
    28.4598950062382, 28.4603010783983, 28.4602554090402, 28.4602871699419, 
    28.4604178938905, 28.4604409569542, 28.460580385231, 28.4606121531285, 
    28.4605449626663, 28.4605423677549, 28.460311628625, 28.4601454853491, 
    28.4596008936146, 28.4602305747069, 28.459888050339, 28.4598424058183, 
    28.4604033554904, 28.4601941673923, 28.459808594271, 28.4600167754613, 
    28.4600270416968, 28.4602136976296, 28.4602326529227, 28.460780767236, 
    28.4610879112809, 28.4614596359738, 28.4615258161975, 28.4614371393666, 
    28.461701236826, 28.4619653365135, 28.4617992370959, 28.4616331402453, 
    28.461600380565, 28.4611933269593, 28.4606314160947), `009` = c(28.3884938819469, 
    28.3991291494431, 28.4065985628763, 28.4104173489313, 28.4146068255518, 
    28.4256803266826, 28.4238708919297, 28.4314322857144, 28.4393698362899, 
    28.4401635654092, 28.4416195512874, 28.443697308483, 28.4486024306673, 
    28.4548524832992, 28.4556046206078, 28.457456083197, 28.4585727177855, 
    28.4596101571606, 28.4596940627478, 28.4599201283979, 28.4637709580809, 
    28.4658190981975, 28.4675964656121, 28.4693941394046, 28.4731174250685, 
    28.4756174378251, 28.4784603727885, 28.4829153881772, 28.4844775260772, 
    28.4909182152346, 28.4949120278993, 28.4981211213728, 28.5005162490627, 
    28.5017114868563, 28.5020595549861, 28.5024981747026, 28.5026878645526, 
    28.5030027481228, 28.5029747624519, 28.502981364463, 28.5030736863932, 
    28.5034776833868, 28.5034959329191, 28.5038668436455, 28.5038850907069, 
    28.5041010936429, 28.5042610671501, 28.5042958012423, 28.5049188190567, 
    28.5051347905828, 28.5048234600677, 28.5045928631841, 28.5046457076724, 
    28.5048138909565, 28.5065226478816, 28.508447119696, 28.5119695430694, 
    28.5128591013956, 28.5140054138731, 28.5160870633279, 28.5179441352946, 
    28.5190661799043, 28.519936664811, 28.5207215309144, 28.5212739244757, 
    28.5216444991972, 28.5214006753231, 28.521643006578, 28.5231836365758, 
    28.5250152565693, 28.5254632426238, 28.526485444833, 28.5432251656557, 
    28.542529924166, 28.5335121158562, 28.5423678332577, 28.5559546601205, 
    28.5573166653937, 28.5581807264982, 28.5596006871624, 28.5596279220476
    ), `010` = c(28.474471643365, 28.4755344437003, 28.4755354352828, 
    28.4772207235164, 28.4837031924224, 28.4991628815303, 28.5054555296438, 
    28.5073623509313, 28.5086213293914, 28.5095143536491, 28.5104368771422, 
    28.5110116477836, 28.5117248857941, 28.511700110621, 28.5117792574717, 
    28.5120296704322, 28.5122403743187, 28.5125335930436, 28.5132334836023, 
    28.5137783964317, 28.5142081161052, 28.5143065792181, 28.5146861086325, 
    28.5151614146978, 28.5151926630474, 28.5150498659623, 28.5150995818892, 
    28.5147915053608, 28.5150713653184, 28.5156558678698, 28.5167056466776, 
    28.5162987439244, 28.5163513853399, 28.5188299654365, 28.5204640732977, 
    28.5212779965398, 28.5226422100855, 28.5229272240745, 28.5235995521255, 
    28.5250065215569, 28.5298969287621, 28.5330588589363, 28.5347301613804, 
    28.5363025743411, 28.5403108834867, 28.5448076615469, 28.5465426591561, 
    28.5533640823294, 28.5582304504621, 28.5648169441483, 28.5671395744164, 
    28.571040867585, 28.5720307990048, 28.5730846721842, 28.5731506190491, 
    28.5733928400798, 28.5735014186948, 28.5738559767499, 28.5739219342504, 
    28.5741854787987, 28.5745478175427, 28.5744588241025, 28.5750962296399, 
    28.5750072409194, 28.5748969428948, 28.5750190860188, 28.5749301053486, 
    28.5746357757441, 28.5746455924802, 28.574740658428, 28.5748841268116, 
    28.5752678021668, 28.5764069409072, 28.5772283918006, 28.57884014518, 
    28.5785536068131, 28.5781256673738, 28.5789044970138, 28.5789356375162, 
    28.5783178803397, 28.5787015620915, 28.5810338413594, 28.582194225733, 
    28.5817101405053, 28.582157724943)), .Names = c("001", "002", 
"003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"))), .Names = c("julian", 
"pot_density"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can't do `dput(dens[1:100,])` as the console won't contain it all unfortunately.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: This might help: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

Comment: I guess it's due to FUN=paste in aggregate. If you put here another function you want to apply to these pot densities per julian, then I guessed you solved it.

Comment: Tried to use "FUN=list" instead, and a few other functions, but none worked out. I'm not sure I understand what is the purpose of "FUN=..." here despite reading the help section of aggregate. "FUN=NULL" does not work. 
Will try to post a subset copy.

Comment: just use the above code and paste it in your post as code

Comment: The thing is that data frames do not lend themselves very well to an a priori unknown amount of columns. I think you need something like `ctd %>% group_by(julian) %>% do()`. This is dplyr syntax that gives a subset of your ctd data frame to the stuff in `do()` (which can be just a sequence of lines of code starting and ending with `{` and `}`) where you can access the `pot_density` with `.$pot_density`. This gives a vector of numbers that you can use to do your real magic on.

Comment: Sorry, i was confused looking at your output. It is dput(dens[1:10,])

Comment: Can you give a better example dataframe? Because this one is mostly NAs. So a bit more samples: dput(dens[1:100,]) And do it before you aggregate of course.

Comment: This is after aggregate still your example, i require before.

Comment: Sorry; should I apply it to ctd then ? I create dens by aggregating stuff, not sure applying `dput` to an empty dens would help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

The one column to multi-column splitting could be performed by first grouping by each date/julian,
splitting by comma, unlisting and conversion to data.frame row

```
DF=data.frame(julian=27548,pot_density=paste(c(28.4698015312665,28.4704581365093,28.4706453687),collapse=","),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF

#  julian                                     pot_density
#1  27548 28.4698015312665,28.4704581365093,28.4706453687


newDF=DF %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(julian) %>% 
      dplyr::do(.,data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(.$pot_density,",")),nrow=1)) ) %>% 
      as.data.frame()

newDF
#  julian               X1               X2            X3
#1  27548 28.4698015312665 28.4704581365093 28.4706453687
```

**Updated dataset:**

For your updated dataset, you can use unlist in the `dplyr::do` function to achieve the desired rectangular data.frame structure

Note that since the length of the 10 vectors is different you will have have NA values in some columns as a result and the number of 
columns is maximum of the length of 10 vectors i.e. 85 in this case

```
sapply(dens$pot_density,length)
# 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 
 # 82  83  83  84  84  84  83  84  81  85

newDens=dens %>% 
          dplyr::group_by(julian) %>% 
          dplyr::do(.,data.frame(matrix(unlist(.$pot_density),nrow=1)) ) %>% 
          as.data.frame()

head(newDens)

  # julian       X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6       X7       X8       X9      X10      X11      X12      X13      X14
# 1  27548 28.46980 28.47046 28.47065 28.47137 28.47160 28.47132 28.47194 28.47164 28.47194 28.47244 28.47294 28.47309 28.47288 28.47310
# 2  27555 28.38543 28.38806 28.39109 28.40103 28.41289 28.42243 28.43977 28.44522 28.44582 28.44576 28.44620 28.44655 28.44736 28.44999
# 3  27562 28.42227 28.42382 28.42443 28.42479 28.42547 28.42512 28.42507 28.42421 28.42399 28.42443 28.42443 28.42527 28.42468 28.42435
# 4  27569 28.36748 28.36746 28.36878 28.37012 28.37175 28.37264 28.37423 28.37468 28.37515 28.37497 28.37476 28.37457 28.37728 28.37809
# 5  27576 28.45268 28.45358 28.45255 28.45186 28.45280 28.45318 28.45289 28.45554 28.45886 28.46282 28.47461 28.47840 28.48306 28.48473
# 6  27583 28.38106 28.38130 28.38171 28.38312 28.38544 28.38715 28.38908 28.39021 28.39180 28.39539 28.39802 28.40041 28.40451 28.40721
       # X15      X16      X17      X18      X19      X20      X21      X22      X23      X24      X25      X26      X27      X28      X29
# 1 28.47376 28.47400 28.47423 28.47386 28.47432 28.47427 28.47501 28.47566 28.47508 28.47558 28.47528 28.47529 28.47534 28.47544 28.47639
# 2 28.45058 28.45241 28.45280 28.45279 28.45242 28.45243 28.45257 28.45329 28.45320 28.45371 28.45462 28.45493 28.45548 28.45603 28.45587
# 3 28.42487 28.42552 28.42493 28.42470 28.42469 28.42460 28.42477 28.42491 28.42480 28.42508 28.42372 28.42351 28.42387 28.42422 28.42406
# 4 28.37909 28.38681 28.39588 28.39948 28.39925 28.40067 28.40377 28.40711 28.40835 28.40862 28.40971 28.40957 28.40982 28.41094 28.41169
# 5 28.48765 28.48769 28.48837 28.48860 28.48843 28.48838 28.48861 28.48836 28.48877 28.48880 28.48866 28.48823 28.48845 28.48855 28.48994
# 6 28.40871 28.41264 28.41362 28.41674 28.42094 28.42703 28.43125 28.43744 28.44327 28.44861 28.45126 28.45242 28.45129 28.45123 28.45237
       # X30      X31      X32      X33      X34      X35      X36      X37      X38      X39      X40      X41      X42      X43      X44
# 1 28.47697 28.47747 28.47791 28.47790 28.47803 28.47818 28.47809 28.47788 28.47792 28.47816 28.47811 28.47780 28.47793 28.47787 28.47827
# 2 28.45652 28.45807 28.45933 28.45977 28.46019 28.46051 28.46100 28.46136 28.46127 28.46158 28.46191 28.46233 28.46503 28.46818 28.46907
# 3 28.42378 28.42353 28.42367 28.42346 28.42334 28.42329 28.42322 28.42341 28.42340 28.42404 28.42429 28.42447 28.42436 28.42467 28.42444
# 4 28.41317 28.41636 28.42153 28.42233 28.42240 28.42396 28.42525 28.42537 28.42547 28.42604 28.42650 28.42772 28.42909 28.43003 28.43136
# 5 28.48980 28.49084 28.49092 28.49133 28.49152 28.49214 28.49238 28.49239 28.49209 28.49234 28.49233 28.49241 28.49260 28.49329 28.49381
# 6 28.45339 28.45486 28.45551 28.45618 28.45713 28.45885 28.46112 28.46298 28.46378 28.46390 28.46541 28.46610 28.46873 28.47033 28.47103
       # X45      X46      X47      X48      X49      X50      X51      X52      X53      X54      X55      X56      X57      X58      X59
# 1 28.47823 28.47792 28.47776 28.47791 28.47761 28.47762 28.47767 28.47726 28.47711 28.47687 28.47735 28.47686 28.47717 28.47754 28.47722
# 2 28.46970 28.46996 28.47060 28.47118 28.47135 28.47296 28.47468 28.47556 28.47722 28.47915 28.47984 28.48097 28.48108 28.48111 28.48129
# 3 28.42407 28.42406 28.42438 28.42469 28.42493 28.42558 28.42621 28.42715 28.42722 28.42752 28.42765 28.42871 28.43017 28.43179 28.43443
# 4 28.43191 28.43311 28.43480 28.43596 28.43673 28.43921 28.44073 28.44223 28.44265 28.44352 28.44448 28.44501 28.44557 28.44542 28.44716
# 5 28.49392 28.49363 28.49379 28.49324 28.49351 28.49468 28.49558 28.49573 28.49635 28.49718 28.49854 28.49863 28.49868 28.50034 28.50022
# 6 28.47487 28.47718 28.48008 28.48167 28.48309 28.48441 28.48660 28.48846 28.49091 28.49313 28.49472 28.49529 28.49647 28.49742 28.49801
       # X60      X61      X62      X63      X64      X65      X66      X67      X68      X69      X70      X71      X72      X73      X74
# 1 28.47667 28.47667 28.47652 28.47673 28.47643 28.47634 28.47668 28.47667 28.47647 28.47646 28.47658 28.47668 28.47670 28.47662 28.47669
# 2 28.48107 28.48153 28.48151 28.48126 28.48123 28.48145 28.48140 28.48129 28.48126 28.48143 28.48146 28.48141 28.48154 28.48136 28.48149
# 3 28.43473 28.43517 28.43597 28.43618 28.43668 28.43699 28.43688 28.43797 28.43824 28.43870 28.43863 28.43913 28.44231 28.44498 28.44527
# 4 28.44915 28.45137 28.45238 28.45239 28.45248 28.45288 28.45327 28.45397 28.45462 28.45597 28.45791 28.45879 28.46073 28.46372 28.46587
# 5 28.50005 28.49965 28.50040 28.50208 28.50291 28.50319 28.50352 28.50502 28.50531 28.50528 28.50728 28.50742 28.51176 28.51329 28.51406
# 6 28.49889 28.49929 28.50054 28.50253 28.50502 28.50801 28.51164 28.51209 28.51328 28.51400 28.51412 28.51475 28.51701 28.51829 28.51830
       # X75      X76      X77      X78      X79      X80      X81      X82      X83      X84 X85
# 1 28.47676 28.47684 28.47698 28.47675 28.47646 28.47656 28.47680 28.47696       NA       NA  NA
# 2 28.48138 28.48152 28.48168 28.48117 28.48099 28.48080 28.48079 28.48080 28.48076       NA  NA
# 3 28.44555 28.44556 28.44747 28.44876 28.44821 28.44815 28.45076 28.45319 28.45599       NA  NA
# 4 28.46681 28.46803 28.46890 28.46963 28.47142 28.47305 28.47342 28.47462 28.47682 28.47908  NA
# 5 28.51426 28.51492 28.51440 28.51432 28.51416 28.51403 28.51449 28.51467 28.51461 28.51462  NA
# 6 28.51946 28.52087 28.52085 28.52243 28.52380 28.52534 28.52637 28.52713 28.52725 28.52821  NA
```

Comment: Seems to be working for that one row, will try to adapt it to the whole data frame, thanks a bunch !

Comment: So the code for the updated dataset works perfectly ! Thank you so much; it does exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, NAs do not matter here (I expected them, sampling was not always done at the same station, hence the different depths) and I do get up to 538 columns with the complete "ctd" dataset. 
Thanks again !

Comment: Glad it worked, please do look at `dplyr`  documentation for its excellent data manipulation capabilities and also this [rstudio cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at solving your problem with a minimum of changes to your code:

```
ctd <- data.frame(pot_density = c(28.7, 27, 26, 25, 24), julian = c(rep(32790, 2), rep(27548, 3)))
dens <- aggregate(pot_density ~ julian, data = ctd, FUN = paste, collapse = "/")
tidyr::separate(dens, pot_density, sep = "/", into = paste0("pot_density.", 1:3))
```

Though you probably should not use `paste` in the first place (numeric to character conversion is probably not what you want).

Comment: Tried it, and got   

    julian pot_density.1 pot_density.2 pot_density.3
    1  27548            26            25            24
    2  32790          28.7            27          <NA>
    Warning message:
    Too few values at 1 locations: 2

Comment: I do agree that I should use the `paste` function, but I don't understand in the first place what is the purpose of that function in aggregate ?

Comment: Which is alright if you have different counts of `plot_density` values per `julian` group (as seems to be the case per your edit).
You'll have to adjust `1:3` to match the maximum count of `plot_density` values

Comment: If you've got a background in SQL, maybe you can relate the `FUN` argument to a summary function in a `GROUP BY` query. Experiment with `aggregate(pot_density ~ julian, data = ctd, FUN = max)` or `FUN = mean` for instance

Comment: No background in SQL sadly. I tried to adapt your code but can't get it to work the way I want yet