# Extracting values from list and assigning it to respective columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with only one row but 95 columns. The value for each column is either a list or a list of lists. Most of the lists have single valued integers. I want the data frame to contain the integer values instead of list elements. In case of lists with multiple values, I want new columns to be assigned and suitably named.

How can I go about this? I've added the dput object for reference.

```
structure(list(post_stories = structure(list(values = structure(list(
    value = 123L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_storytellers = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 122L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_stories_by_action_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(share = 2L, like = 121L), .Names = c("share", 
        "like"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_storytellers_by_action_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(share = 2L, like = 121L), .Names = c("share", 
        "like"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_story_adds = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 123L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_story_adds_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 122L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_story_adds_by_action_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(like = 121L, share = 2L), .Names = c("like", 
        "share"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(like = 122L, share = 2L), .Names = c("like", 
        "share"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s_autoplayed = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s_clicked_to_play = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_30s_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_impressions = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_impressions_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_consumptions_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_consumptions = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_consumptions_by_type_unique = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = structure(list(`video play` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `other clicks` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `photo view` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `link clicks` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("video play", 
        "other clicks", "photo view", "link clicks"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_consumptions_by_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(`video play` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `other clicks` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `photo view` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), `link clicks` = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("video play", 
        "other clicks", "photo view", "link clicks"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_action_by_type_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(like = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), comment = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), share = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("like", "comment", 
        "share"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_interests_action_by_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(like = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), comment = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame"), share = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("like", "comment", 
        "share"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 4248L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 3642L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_paid_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_fan = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 4108L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_fan_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 3527L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_fan_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_fan_paid_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 4171L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_organic_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 3578L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_viral = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 77L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_viral_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 74L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_by_story_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(other = 77L), .Names = "other", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_by_story_type_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(other = 74L), .Names = "other", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(total = 4248L, unpaid = 4248L, 
            paid = 0L), .Names = c("total", "unpaid", "paid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = structure(list(total = 3642L, 
            unpaid = 3642L, paid = 0L), .Names = c("total", "unpaid", 
        "paid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_consumptions = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 355L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_consumptions_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 75L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_consumptions_by_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(`other clicks` = 283L, `photo view` = 72L), .Names = c("other clicks", 
        "photo view"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_consumptions_by_type_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(`other clicks` = 29L, `photo view` = 69L), .Names = c("other clicks", 
        "photo view"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_engaged_users = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 186L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_negative_feedback = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 1L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_negative_feedback_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 1L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_negative_feedback_by_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(hide_clicks = 1L), .Names = "hide_clicks", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_negative_feedback_by_type_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(hide_clicks = 1L), .Names = "hide_clicks", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_engaged_fan = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 179L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_fan_reach = structure(list(values = structure(list(value = 3527L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_anger_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_by_type_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(like = 109L, love = 0L, wow = 3L, 
            haha = 9L, sorry = 0L, anger = 0L), .Names = c("like", 
        "love", "wow", "haha", "sorry", "anger"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_haha_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 9L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_like_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 109L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_love_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_sorry_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_reactions_wow_total = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 3L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_avg_time_watched = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_organic_unique = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_complete_views_paid_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_retention_graph = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_retention_graph_clicked_to_play = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_retention_graph_autoplayed = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_organic_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_views_paid = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_paid_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_length = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_views = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_autoplayed = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_clicked_to_play = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_views_10s = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_unique = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_autoplayed = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_clicked_to_play = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_views_10s_paid = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_10s_sound_on = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_sound_on = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_view_time = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time_organic = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_view_time_organic = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time_paid = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = c(0L, 0L, 0L), end_time = c("2017-03-10T08:00:00+0000", 
        "2017-03-11T08:00:00+0000", "2017-03-12T08:00:00+0000"
        )), .Names = c("value", "end_time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L))), .Names = "values"), post_video_view_time_paid = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = 0L), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time_by_age_bucket_and_gender = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time_by_region_id = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_views_by_distribution_type = structure(list(values = structure(list(
        value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values"), 
    post_video_view_time_by_distribution_type = structure(list(
        values = structure(list(value = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c(NA, 
        -1L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "value", class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), .Names = "values")), .Names = c("post_stories", 
"post_storytellers", "post_stories_by_action_type", "post_storytellers_by_action_type", 
"post_story_adds", "post_story_adds_unique", "post_story_adds_by_action_type", 
"post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique", "post_video_complete_views_30s", 
"post_video_complete_views_30s_autoplayed", "post_video_complete_views_30s_clicked_to_play", 
"post_video_complete_views_30s_organic", "post_video_complete_views_30s_paid", 
"post_video_complete_views_30s_unique", "post_interests_impressions", 
"post_interests_impressions_unique", "post_interests_consumptions_unique", 
"post_interests_consumptions", "post_interests_consumptions_by_type_unique", 
"post_interests_consumptions_by_type", "post_interests_action_by_type_unique", 
"post_interests_action_by_type", "post_impressions", "post_impressions_unique", 
"post_impressions_paid", "post_impressions_paid_unique", "post_impressions_fan", 
"post_impressions_fan_unique", "post_impressions_fan_paid", "post_impressions_fan_paid_unique", 
"post_impressions_organic", "post_impressions_organic_unique", 
"post_impressions_viral", "post_impressions_viral_unique", "post_impressions_by_story_type", 
"post_impressions_by_story_type_unique", "post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid", 
"post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique", "post_consumptions", 
"post_consumptions_unique", "post_consumptions_by_type", "post_consumptions_by_type_unique", 
"post_engaged_users", "post_negative_feedback", "post_negative_feedback_unique", 
"post_negative_feedback_by_type", "post_negative_feedback_by_type_unique", 
"post_engaged_fan", "post_fan_reach", "post_reactions_anger_total", 
"post_reactions_by_type_total", "post_reactions_haha_total", 
"post_reactions_like_total", "post_reactions_love_total", "post_reactions_sorry_total", 
"post_reactions_wow_total", "post_video_avg_time_watched", "post_video_complete_views_organic", 
"post_video_complete_views_organic_unique", "post_video_complete_views_paid", 
"post_video_complete_views_paid_unique", "post_video_retention_graph", 
"post_video_retention_graph_clicked_to_play", "post_video_retention_graph_autoplayed", 
"post_video_views_organic", "post_video_views_organic_unique", 
"post_video_views_paid", "post_video_views_paid", "post_video_views_paid_unique", 
"post_video_length", "post_video_views", "post_video_views", 
"post_video_views_unique", "post_video_views_autoplayed", "post_video_views_clicked_to_play", 
"post_video_views_10s", "post_video_views_10s", "post_video_views_10s_unique", 
"post_video_views_10s_autoplayed", "post_video_views_10s_clicked_to_play", 
"post_video_views_10s_organic", "post_video_views_10s_paid", 
"post_video_views_10s_paid", "post_video_views_10s_sound_on", 
"post_video_views_sound_on", "post_video_view_time", "post_video_view_time", 
"post_video_view_time_organic", "post_video_view_time_organic", 
"post_video_view_time_paid", "post_video_view_time_paid", "post_video_view_time_by_age_bucket_and_gender", 
"post_video_view_time_by_region_id", "post_video_views_by_distribution_type", 
"post_video_view_time_by_distribution_type"), row.names = "values", class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994206/unlist-a-list-within-a-data-frame?

Comment: it's easier if when you're getting the impressions endpoint to not use fromJSON, but `GET` and `content()` . It will return a list instead of simplified vector.